# Get vue object inside object into console

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a object in my Vue called 'file'.
When I use console.log to look at its contents its as below in the picture

```
console.log(file);
```

[image]

But now I want to see the contents of exif so I tried

```
console.log(file.exif)
```

The problem is that its always 'undefined'. What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: did you try doing `file.Object.exif` ??? coz i see `Object` is having the param `exif` and not `file` itself

Comment: Yes I just did. Its still 'undefined'

Comment: then try copying the object to a temp global variable in chrome console and see if you can really access `exif`, to do that just right click on object logged you see an option to store as global variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I notice is that `exif` doesn't have the `...` that all the other properties have. This suggests that it doesn't have a property getter. As reactive properties all have getters it would suggest that this property was added later than the others without using `Vue.set`.

With that in mind it is worth noting that objects logged to the console are live. If you hover over the little blue i icon you'll get some indication of this. The console does not take a copy of the properties when you log an object. It will only grab the property values when you expand the object in the console.

So what I believe is happening is that the property `exif` does not exist at the point you are logging out the object but it is subsequently added before you click on the object in the console.

There are other things you can try logging to double check. e.g. `console.log(JSON.stringify(file))` or `console.log(Object.keys(file))`. These should all confirm that the `exif` property does not exist at that point.

Comment: Thanks. You are probably right. The trouble is that I am using vue-image-upload-resize which returns a file object and it seems EXIF data is not available in that function. Strangely by the time when I look at console, its there - gets embedded somehow